# How to fetch a specific value and sum of multiple values in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am facing a common problem in which, I want to fetch only single value from a field that are duplicates values and also get their `sum` value respectively.

For Example:

[image]

I just want to get sum of "profit" of particular year with their year label.

Comment: `sum` and `group by`

Comment: select year, sum(profit) as totalprofit from `tablename` group by year

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use group by to get the desired result

```
SELECT
    year,
    sum(PROFIT) 
FROM
    YOURTABLE 
GROUP BY
    year
```